# IOS: "Failed: Method is not implemented" error when I tried to perform some touch actions

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium, protractor, appium

I am testing Hybrid app and I tried to perform some touch actions on iOS like doubleTap and tapAndHold on WebView. And I get "Failed: Method is not implemented" error.

I tried the below code :

```
browser.switchTo().frame(0);
return browser.touchActions().doubleTap(element).perform();
```

But when I try

```
return browser.touchActions().tap(element).perform();
```

everything is ok.
For Android this code works fine.

Appium: 1.7.1
Protractor: 5.1.2
webdriver-manager 12.0.6.
MacOS High Sierra

So how can I perform this touch actions on iOS?

conf.js:

```
var wd = require('wd'),
  wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(require('protractor'), wd);
const config = {
  sync: false,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: '',
    appiumVersion: "1.7.1",
    deviceName: "iPhone 8",
    deviceOrientation: "portrait",
    platformName: "iOS",
    platformVersion: "11.0",
    app:"",
    bundleId:'',
    launchTimeout: 20000,
    webviewConnectRetries: 1,
    autoAcceptAlerts: true,
    autoWebview: true,
    waitForAppScript: 'true',
    nativeInstrumentsLib:'false',
    showIOSLog:'false',
    newCommandTimeout: 5000
  },
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  allScriptsTimeout: 1500000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    print: function () {
    },
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1500000
  },
  suites: {
    smoke: ['./automation/smoke/*.js'],
  },
  beforeLaunch: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.wBridge=wdBridge;
    browser.getProcessedConfig()
      .then(function (config) {
        browser.appPackage = config.capabilities.appPackage;
        browser.bundleId = config.capabilities.bundleId;
        browser.deviceProperties = config.capabilities.deviceProperties;
        browser.platformname = config.capabilities.platformName;
        var iOSProperties = {'identifier': browser.bundleId},
          androidProperties = {'identifier': browser.appPackage},
          params = browser.platformname.toLowerCase() === 'iOS' ? androidProperties : iOSProperties;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        wdBrowser.currentContext().then(function(context) {
          console.log('#context');
          console.log(context);
        });
      });

  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: false
};
exports.config = config;
```

Comment: Have you tried `.tap(element).tap(element)` ?

Comment: yes, working like two taps, not like doubleTap

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `doubleTap` function in [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md) project, so the error you get is expected to see.
2. If you check appium server commands for [doubleTap](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/5480b68d36e679e43e022ca4964db5e1ef862a20/commands-yml/commands/interactions/touch/double-tap.yml), you will notice that for `wd` client code is the same to [tap](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/5480b68d36e679e43e022ca4964db5e1ef862a20/commands-yml/commands/interactions/touch/tap.yml) code, so it really looks like **doubleTap is not supported by `wd` yet**

So far I see 2 options:

1) Play more with existing functions in `wd` touch actions, e.g. try

```
const location = await element.getLocation()
const action = new wd.TouchAction()
action.press({x: location.x, y: location.y})
  .release()
  .press({x: location.x, y: location.y})
  .release()
await browser.performTouchAction(action)
```

2) Implement doubleTap in [wd](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/d615cc94926060c382aa9da7dcd35ea3373e8001/lib/actions.js) project looking into examples from java or python client.